# Can i combine bluetooth button with a button in my web page?

Tags: javascript, html, bluetooth

I am trying in my web application(html,javascript) to simulate a simple button click on my page with a click on my bluetooth device.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the Bluetooth device implemented? Is it actually a keyboard with one key? See if you can hear it with a keydown event. If it is actually a joypad implementation, you could use the game pad API. Clarify your Bluetooth device.

Comment: I don't have something specific in my mind. I was thinking a classic blueooth device for a mobile but I am really open in propositions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Bluetooth API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API), but it isn't standard and has very limited browser support. A brief skim of the spec doesn't convince me it has the features you need for this anyway.

You could approach this by moving responsibility for handling bluetooth away from the page. A program could both listen for the bluetooth button and then inform the browser when the button was pressed.

You could do this with, for instance, [this Node.js module for flic.io BLE buttons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-flic-buttons) and then use Web Sockets to communicate with the browser.

Comment: Yes this seems legit to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend for the guidance.